# Retrofit 2 и проектирование приложения

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Добрый день господа. Подскажите пожалуйста неопытному нужно ли реализовывать запросы Http с помощью Retrofit2 в отдельном потоке? В интернете мнения расходятся и мало где это вообще обсуждается. Видел информацию что Retrofit2 как раз позволяет проектирование приложения без отдельного потока для запросов, так ли это ? Приложение простенькое запросы все производятся по инициативе пользователя. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ретрофит самостоятельно выводит всё в другой поток.
А вот для ответов лучше уже использовать AsyncTask.

Современный вариант - работа через Rx (реактивный поток). Вот неплохой материал на вашу тему https://habrahabr.ru/post/305478/

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit позволяет выполнять запросы как синхронно, так и асинхронно.

Асинхронные запросы выполняются в отдельных (отличных от UI-потока) потоках.

Подробнее: [Retrofit — Synchronous and Asynchronous Requests](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-synchronous-and-asynchronous-requests).